# Building dict combinations to match a target sum in Python

Tags: python, dictionary, combinations, reduce

I have a dict made of N integer values like this:

```
units = {'trooper':2, 'tank':10, 'helicopter':12}
```

And I also have a target value... say 120.

I am trying to find all possible results of the equation:

```
a*units['trooper'] + b*units['tank'] + c*units['helicopter'] = 120
```

So the result would look something like:

```
60*trooper
55*trooper + 1*tank
54*trooper + 1*helicopter
```

And so on with all possible combinations of the N keys in the dict...

How can I go about building this ?

Comment: You might wanna have a look at this : http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/702951/easiest-way-to-solve-system-of-linear-equations-involving-singular-matrix

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Searching for solutions to these kinds of problems is easiest if you know what they are called.   Google for [Diophantine equations](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Diophantine_equation).

In the Python world, you can use the [Sympy package](http://docs.sympy.org/dev/modules/solvers/diophantine.html#diophantine-docs) which includes a Diophantine equation solver.  That package makes short work of your problem:

```
from sympy import symbols
from sympy.solvers.diophantine import diop_solve

trooper, tank, helicopter = symbols('trooper tank helicopter', integer=True)
print diop_solve(2*trooper + 10*tank + 12*helicopter - 120)
```

It outputs:

```
(5*t - trooper + 60, -6*t + trooper - 60, trooper)
```

You can also search for ["ways to make change"](http://www.maa.org/frank-morgans-math-chat-293-ways-to-make-change-for-a-dollar) which is another way of expressing the problem.   A related problem is called called [The Knapsack Problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Knapsack_problem) and it is famously difficult to solve.  The math behind solving general systems of linear Diophantine equations is a bit involved.  Here are some resources:

- http://www.math.udel.edu/~lazebnik/papers/dior1.pdf
- http://www.dcc.fc.up.pt/~apt/onlinepapers/epia97_final.pdf
- https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Diophantine_equation#System_of_linear_Diophantine_equations
- http://www.math.utah.edu/~carlson/hsp2004/PythonShortCourse.pdf

Comment: Not sure this is "technically" an answer - but it gets +1 from me for assisting the OP regarding search terms

Comment: Thank you for your very informative answer.

I'm still a bit confused though:
How do I interpret the result of the diop_solve function ?

"(5*t - trooper + 60, -6*t + trooper - 60, trooper)"

How do I generate all possible combinations from this ?

Answer (score 0):

Something like this would work for small values of target value:

```
units = {'trooper':2, 'tank':10, 'helicopter':12}
total = 120
for i in range(int(total/units['helicopter'])):
    for j in range(int(total/units['tank'])):
            if (total-units['helicopter']*i-units['tank']*j)%2==0 and (total-units['helicopter']*i-units['tank']*j)>0:
                print ((total-units['helicopter']*i-units['tank']*j)/2,j,i)
```